# flex column reverse with scrollbar work difference

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have flex list with scroll.
If I add a new item to head then scrollbar position on top -> scrollbar remains on top and we see new element.

[image]

Then I set reverse to flex column for it list. I expect the same behavior only from below.

But I get "jump" after add new element if I scroll up then scrolldown and press 'ADD' btn.

What is problem? why scrollbar is not 'sticky' like as nornal column flex?

[image]

sandbox:
https://codepen.io/shenkonor-mail-ru/pen/mdqveey

Chrome 96 windows

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="h-screen bg-teal-200 flex flex-col">
  <div class="h-20 flex-shrink-0 bg-indigo-400">header</div>
  <div class="flex-grow grid grid-cols-[300px_1fr] grid-rows-1 bg-green-200 min-h-0">
    <div>left short content</div>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
      <div id="list" class="flex-grow bg-rose-300 overflow-y-scroll flex flex-col-reverse">
      </div>
      <button id="btn" class="bg-fuchsia-800 rounded shadow">ADD</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="h-20 flex-shrink-0 bg-indigo-400">footer</div>
</div>


var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

let i = 1;

btn.onclick = function(event) {

 add()
}

function add(){
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.classList.add("h-60", "border", "border-black", "text-xl", "shrink-0");
  div.textContent += "ADDED " + i;
  i++;
   document.getElementById('list').prepend(div);
 // document.getElementById('list').append(div);
}

for (var z = 0; z < 6; z++) {
  add();
}
```

UPDATE 1: (remove watch  More detailed update 2\3)

**Update 2**. More detailed video

1. open sandbox in new tab
2. then page init we see "**element 6**" and the scroll is pressed down
3. I add a new element, and we see that everything is fine. The scroll is pressed down and a new **element 7** is shown
4. then I the scroll a little up and down it to the very bottom and press btn for add new element.
5. And then we see that the element was added, but the scroll did not press down and we see the old **element 7**.

[image]

**Update 3**. Proof that without flex-reverse, the scroll is always pressed up. In both cases, when adding an element after initialization and after moving the scroll

[image]

Comment: There is no "behavior" here. The scroll position doesn't change in either case. When inserting at the top, it just happens that the scroll position is already at the right position to see the element. Have you tried [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)?

Comment: So here's the video I added. That the first time after loading, when adding an element, the scroll is pressed to the bottom. but if I move scroll a little and press it down and try to add an element , the scroll is no longer pressed

Comment: @RoToRa If I remove flex-reverse, then in both cases (at the first download and after I touch the scroll) it will always be pressed to the top when adding elements

Comment: I tested this behaviour in both Chrome and Firefox with your example code and I do not get this behaviour. In both cases the scrollbar remains at the bottom when a new element is added. Can you confirm if this happens when using your example code above?

Comment: @DreamTeK added "Update 2"  watch the video and description

Comment: well, did I find a bug in html or what?

Comment: @RoToRa \ DreamTeK added update 3. proof what without flex-reverse  behavior difference

Comment: we can't do it without @temani-afif  :D